# SQL Server : "Error converting data type nvarchar to float" - fast allocation of invalid rows

Tags: sql-server-2008, type-conversion

I try to run a query on a table and end up with this error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>   Error converting data type nvarchar to float.

The query:

```
SELECT 
    *, CAST(REPLACE(a.ts_value, ',', '.') AS FLOAT) AS value
FROM 
    importFromExcel_timeseries a
```

Is there any hack for a quick allocation of rows that yield this error?

I tried to run put a `WHERE isnumeric(a.ts_value)` filter, but this does not help

Answer (score 0):

"does not help", does that mean you get the same error?  If so, just remove the cast from the select and it should return the rows you're looking for.